# How to delete part of the JSON that is corrupted in a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has one column with rows as json, and I am able to parse them correctly as long as a particular key is removed.

```
   id | email     | phone no | details
-------------------------------------------------
0  10 | abc@g.com |   123   | {"a" : "hello", "b" : {"x": "whatever"....}, "c": "check"}
1  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   | {"a" : "bye", "b" : {"x": "ignore"....}, "c": "cool"}
```

The column details has a key called - "b", which has many key value pairs inside it and some are corrupted because there is comma or inverted commas missing. I don't care about it because I don't need it. Can I just removed that portion of the JSON, please?

I want it like below:

```
   id | email     | phone no | details
-------------------------------------------------
0  10 | abc@g.com |   123   | {"a" : "hello", "c": "check"}
1  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   | {"a" : "bye", "c": "cool"}
```

I will need to spit that key/value in details into rows and columns for "details" and I am abae to do that if I remove that one corrupted key. I have millions of records so a way to ignore that key for all the rows in the "details" column is what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Removing it will be difficult, since any pattern you try to match on could be included in the corrupt data.

Comment: It would be better to fix the problem that causes the corrupt JSON in the first place.

Comment: What is the dtype of value. It looks like a dict but I suppose this is a dict-like string?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments, we have asked to fix the JSON but the source team is unable to do it. Actually that new key was introduced recently for some other use which we dont need to consume. It lead to my existing code to fail.

Comment: @Corralien - yes, that is a JSON string inside a dataframe column.

Comment: Do you know the name of the key ('b') and the name of the next key ('c') with your real data?

Comment: yes, I do. Like I know key 'c' will follow key 'b'. But 'b' can have multiple key/values inside it and some of them are incorrectly formatted.

Comment: And last question I hope. Do you know if `{ }` are well balanced or not?

Comment: If in 'b' there are 3 open braces, there must be 3 closing braces.

Comment: May I know what you mean by well balanced? If you mean they are equal open and close curly braces then yes, but then it has multiple such braces inside it. Like "b": {"x" : "try", "y" : "{"i" : "hello"}", z :  "corrupted_key"},

Comment: so, yes the answer is the braces as I see are correct, the corrupted thing is because either comma is missing or they have invertered commas before array or dict like in the key "i" above.

Comment: I am trying to get the keys as columns and values as rows:
data = df.pop('details').apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series) -- This wont work as a particular key/value pair is corrupt. It throws the error: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 100 let say. For any records that doesn't have b, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a regular expression with `str.replace`:

```
PAT = re.compile(r',\s*"b"\s*:\s*{.*?}\s*,\s*')
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace(PAT, ', ')
print(df)

# Output:
   id      email  phone no                        details
0  10  abc@g.com       123  {"a" : "hello", "c": "check"}
1  12  xyz@g.com       789     {"a" : "bye", "c": "cool"}
```

Comment: @trojanhorse. Can you try my code on your dataframe, please?

Comment: yes, I am trying it now.

Comment: it did, remove the key that is a problem but I still see the same error because the remaining keys still seem to have some issue with formatting. I am looking into that part. May be I can ask you more questions once I test few things. This is wonderful again. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have a query, instead of removing the one which is corrupted, do you know how can I rather keep the keys I want? I am asking this because there are multiple such corrupted keys now coming, and to deal with so many regexes, if I can filter out those 3 or 4 keys that I need which I am sure are good, will that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is gross and ugly, but may work if "b" always contains a dictionary, or at least curly braces filled with stuff that is not a closing curly brace:

```
import re
import json

# attempt to delete dictionaries associated with "b" key:
fixed = [re.sub(r'"b" ?: ?{[^}]+}, ?', '', s) for s in df['details']]

try:
    # test for valid JSON
    [json.loads(f) for f in fixed]
    df['details'] = fixed
except json.JSONDecodeError:
    print('whoops, this ugly hack failed')
```

Comment: it does contain curly braces and arrays inside the value for that key - "b"

Comment: in that case it'll be hard to delete the "b" part, if its form is not definable.  Do you have a specification for the remainder?  For example if you know "a" has a certain form and always precedes "b", "c" has a known form and is after "b", you can try the inverse match.  Otherwise this looks intractable.

Comment: Hi AbbeGijly, the pattern is distinctive and we are aware of the preceding and successive keys in this case, however the form of the key/values may differ. Sequence however won't.